# Unity compile errors after upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I had my Project on the Unity Cloud made with Unity 2018 (I don't remember the exact version).
Today I downloaded the latest version of Unity (2019.3.2f1) and tried to open my project.
I'm receiving a lot of errors like these:

[image]

Also, if I open the project with visual studio it compiles with no error.

I am not able to fix them in order to compile the project in Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old version of package manager. Try to **"Reset packages to default".**

[image]